# Fourier series of $\log(a +b\cos(x))$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, taylor-series

By numerical computation it seems like, if $a_0 < a_1$:
$$
\begin{multline}
\log({a_0}^2 + {a_1}^2 + 2 a_0 a_1 \cos(\omega t)) = \log({a_0}^2 + {a_1}^2) \\
+ \frac{a_0}{a_1}\cos(\omega t) 
- \frac{1}{2}\frac{{a_0}^2}{{a_1}^2}\cos(2\omega t) 
+ \frac{1}{3}\frac{{a_0}^3}{{a_1}^3}\cos(3\omega t) 
- \frac{1}{4}\frac{{a_0}^4}{{a_1}^4}\cos(4\omega t) \ldots 
\end{multline}
$$
If $a_0 > a_1$, the two term must be exchanged.

I'm quite confident in this solution but I cannot find a way to prove it mathematically...

Would be nice to know the reason of this result!

Comment: Looks like the real part of $\log(1+e^{i\omega t})$, give or take some constants.

Comment: You are totally right! This is the good approach.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's consider
$$
f(x) = \log (1+q^2+2q\cos x) = \log |1+qe^{ix}|^2 ,
$$
which differs from your function only by the additive constant $2\log a_1$ if we take $q=a_0/a_1$. Since $|q|<1$, we can use the Taylor series of $\log(1+z)$ to write
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)  = 2\,\textrm{Re}\; \log (1+qe^{ix}) = 2\,\textrm{Re}\sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{q^n}{n} e^{inx} \\
= 2\sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{q^n}{n} \cos nx .
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for. Perfect! Good idea to use the complex notation.

Comment: Sorry to be a stickler, but I think you need $(-1)^{n-1}$ in the summand of the Maclaurin series expansion above, unless I missed something?

Comment: @Procore: Yes, thanks, corrected now.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Do you thing it is possible to find a solution for the more general case proposed in the title? I'm trying to solve the case $\log({a_0}^2 + {a_1}^2 + 2 a_0 a_1 \cos(\omega t) + {a_2}^2)$ and just adding this little ${a_2}^2$ prevent me to find a nice solution.

Comment: @AlisterTrabattoni: I don't have any ideas for this off the top of my head, and my guess would be that these Fourier coefficients can't be found explicitly, but I could be wrong about this of course.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I found the way to apply your solution to the more general case. See the edit on my original post.

Comment: You could also add it as an answer, that would probably be clearer. @AlisterTrabattoni

Answer (score 7):

To apply the solution proposed by @ChristianRemling to the more general case stated in the title you need to do the following:

The formula implies $a > 0$ and $|b| < a$. To solve the problem, we reformulate the formula as:
$$
\begin{align}
r|1 + qe^{ix}|^2
&= r(1 + qe^{ix})(1 + qe^{-ix}) \\
&= r(1 + 2q\cos x + q^2) \\
& = a + b\cos x \\
\end{align}
$$

This requires to solve the following system:
$$
\begin{align}
a &= r(1 + q^2) \\
b &= 2rq
\end{align}
$$

From the two possible solutions we take the one where $|q|<1$ which is mandatory for the Taylor expansion. 
$$
\begin{align}
q = \frac{a - \sqrt{a^{2} - b^{2}}}{b} \\
r = \frac{a + \sqrt{a^{2} - b^{2}}}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Finally, Taylor series expansion solve the problem:
$$
\begin{align}
\log (a + b\cos x)
&= \log r 
+ 2\log | 1 + qe^{ix} | \\
&= \log r 
+ 2 \sum {(-1)}^{n-1} \frac{q^n}{n} e^{inx} \\
&= \log r 
+ 2 \sum {(-1)}^{n-1} \frac{q^n}{n} \cos nx
\end{align}
$$